# Can CoffeeScript be compiled to Haxe?

Tags: coffeescript, haxe, code-translation

I'm learning Haxe now, and I'm wondering if it's possible for any programming language to be compiled to Haxe (instead of from Haxe.) If there isn't any programming language that can be compiled to Haxe in its entirety, then could at least a small subset of a programming language (such as Coffeescript) be compiled to Haxe?

Comment: Technically, anything could be compiled to anything (aside from the different set of objects provided by the environment) as long as the target language is turing-complete

Comment: @JanDvorak I recently found a compiler than can translate Javascript to Coffeescript: http://js2coffee.org/ If Javascript could be compiled to Haxe, then Coffeescript could also be compiled to Haxe, via this compiler.

Comment: Definitely not via this compiler. You'd need a Coffeescript to Javascript compiler (which I'm sure exists ;-) ) to compound a Javascript to Haxe compiler.

Comment: @JanDvorak However, it looks like it's possible to compile Haxe to Coffeescript (via a Javascript-to-Coffeescript compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505519/can-haxe-be-compiled-to-coffeescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to compile coffeescript or similar into Haxe.

CoffeeScript is a source-to-source compiler, so you would change need to change it from going CoffeeScript->JS to CoffeeScript->Haxe,

I'm not sure how difficult it would be, and you have to remember that Haxe has a bunch of features that Javascript doesn't, all of which would need to be represented in the "new" coffeescript.  Things such as: type information, enums, typedefs, iterators, macros, conditional compilation, untyped blocks, metadata, property access etc.  You would need to figure out how to represent each of these in coffeescript in a way which doesn't conflict with itself or with existing syntax.

I too have thought it might be nice, as CoffeeScript has such a clean syntax, but then looking at the complexity of getting it to work I decided that curly brackets and semi colons aren't so bad :)

Comment: Yeah, I still prefer Javascript over Coffeescript (because I find that the lack of semicolons makes Coffeescript more difficult to read, despite being less verbose.)

Comment: @AndersonGreen you find the lack of semicolons making it more difficult to read?? It's just a character sitting at the end of (almost) every line. In which way would having it there increase readability?

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck I meant to write "curly braces" instead of "semicolons": the lack of semicolons actually helps readability.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Hehe, yes, that is more understandable... I too have actually started using javascript over coffee script more and more as well...