# Can Haxe be compiled to Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript, haxe

I'm wondering whether it's possible to compile Haxe to Coffeescript - are there any tools that are available for this? I find Coffeescript's syntax to be much more concise than that of Javascript, so I'd like to find a Coffeescript target for Haxe (if it exists.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haxe [already has a Javascript target](http://haxe.org/doc/start/js), and there is already a Javascript-to-Coffeescript that is available ( http://js2coffee.org/ ), so it should be possible, as long as js2coffee does not make any errors in compiling Javascript to Coffeescript.

Comment: Sounds like a decent way to do it.  What are you aiming for with this?  If it's converting a Haxe code base to coffeescript I guess that makes sense, but if you're still coding in Haxe it seems like just another inbetween layer... and I rarely look at the generated source code anyway :)  If you were really committed to getting this to work you could also look into custom JS generators, but that seems dark magic to me...